# Can't read from VEML6030 (or only get 0x0000) via I²C using Renesas r5F104GK

Tags: c, i2c

My problem:
I have connected a VEML6030 (Ambient Light Sensor from Vishay) to my µC.
If I want to read this sensor, I only get 0x0000 as an answer.

I'm programming in c on a Renesas [r5F104GK](https://www.avnet.com/wps/wcm/connect/onesite/e0f2523d-c556-4e05-95c1-e6345745cc6b/Renesas-RL78G14-user-manual.pdf?MOD=AJPERES&CVID=mB9UyJR&CVID=mB9UyJR&attachment=false&id=1551722775009).
I used Applilet as a code generator.

I have the [data sheet](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84366/veml6030.pdf) and an [application note](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84367/designingveml6030.pdf) as documentation. I have also already spent days searching online - unfortunately unsuccessful so far.

I also have a Lis3DH sensor on my PCB, which is connected to the same I²C bus.
I can separate both components from the bus with a jumper.

What I have already achieved:

- Depending on the level of the ADDR pin, I see an ack on the bus.
  [identify veml6030](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEdMr.png)
- The communication with the Lis3DH works (read & write)
- I get protocol-compliant Ack / NACK from the sensor.
- The system is operated at 3V

If I try to read output, I only get 0x000:
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZd4q.png)

During the tests I am sure that only the VEML6030 is contacted.

I would be very happy if someone here could share their experience with the VEML6030 and, if necessary, have a tip on what I'm doing wrong.

In the end, I'm sure that the problem is in front of the monitor ;)

Update (@Lundin)

1. How can I move my ticket to electronics.stackexchange.com?
2. Unfortunately I can only publish a part of the [schematic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsMwr.png)

2.1) SDA & SCL have got 10k Pullups

2.2) SDA is connected to µC Pin 18 (P14/RxD2/SI20/SDA20/TRDIOD0/(SCLA0))

2.3) SCL is connected to µC Pin 17 (P15/PCLBUZ1/SCK20/SCL20/TRDIOB0/(SDAA0))

2.4) INT is connected to µC Pin 36 (P140/PCLBUZ0/INTP6)

The Connector at ADDR is just used to get the correct footprint on the PCB. In real it is a Jumper with 3 pins.

P.S.: Solved Communication
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSZYp.png)

Comment: Questions that are in the borderland between hardware and software are better off at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ (MCU firmware questions are perfectly on-topic there too). It would help a lot if you could post a simple schematic though.

Comment: I could solve my problem.
I send a "stop" after my "set register". I've to edit the automatic generated code to distinguish between "send" and "set register".

For all successors with similar problems, I have attached a figure with a functioning communication in the appendix.

Comment: @Michael We don't add things like 'solved' to title. If your issue has been solved then  you should write an answer and then 'accept it'. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is the correct way now.

My problem is solved.

I've to send only a "Start".